# fillRect doesn't apply big width and height values

Tags: html5-canvas

I use the canvas tag with a Javascript code to draw a rectangle:

```
var canvas=document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle='#FF0000';

ctx.fillRect(0,0,80,100);
```

for the fillRect method, if i give big values for the width and height, i noticed they won't be applied, such an example:

```
ctx.fillRect(0,0,1000,1000);
```

will give something like:

[image]

Am i missing something? is there any limits for the width and height. According to the documentation, i didn't find anything related to that. Please help.

Comment: are you getting any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: Yes, no error, everything is ok in the console. I edited my post with a screenshot of the `ctx.fillRect(0,0,1000,1000);` example.

Comment: you must be setting the canvas height and width less than the fillRect height and width... post your code to jsfiddle.com so I can explain what it's doing.

Comment: Oh, yes, i forget to explicitly set the width and height of the canvas: `<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="1000">`, otherwise, the `width` and `height` of the `fillRect` method will be limited to 300,150. Thanx for you help :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you've got your `width` and `height` of the `canvas` set to less than the rectangle's dimensions. Try setting those explicitly like this:

```
<canvas width="1500" height="1500"></canvas>
```